# Error printing formatted key, value string

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I get an `IOError: [Errno 0] Error` when printing formatted key value pairs of a dictionary as follows:

Suppose I have a dictionary just holding strings (all the values of the dictionary are strings representing some parameters of my run):

```
        sub_params = {'n_points': n_points, 
                      'n_cores': n_cores, 
                      'input_dat': input_dat, 
                      'input_png': input_png,
                      'algorithm': algorithm, 
                      'sub_size': sub_size, 
                      'n_iterations': n_iterations, 
                      'run_idx': dir_index,
                      'img': img}
```

Now a function which gets all the parameters und thus creates the dict above and calls:

```
    print '\n' + 30*'= '
    print '\tRun parameters:'
    for key, value in sub_params.iteritems():
        print '{:20}: {}'.format(key, value)
    print '{:20}: {}'.format('iter_idx', iter_idx)
```

I loop over runs holding different parameter sets. It works for some time and then suddenly crashes:

```
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
        Run parameters:
n_cores             : 1
n_iterations        : 5
sub_size            : None
run_idx             : 7
img                 : square.png
algorithm           : chan_merge_var
input_dat           : points_n_50000_img_square.dat
input_png           : points_n_50000_img_square.png
n_points            : 50000
iter_idx            : 0

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
        Run parameters:
n_cores             : 1
n_iterations        : 5
sub_size            : None
run_idx             : 7
img                 : square.png
algorithm           : chan_merge_var
input_dat           : points_n_50000_img_square.dat
input_png           : points_n_50000_img_square.png
n_points            : 50000
iter_idx            : 1

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
        Run parameters:
n_cores             : 1
n_iterations        : 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
sub_size            : None
  File "C:/Users/mathee/CLionProjects/dphpc-project/python/scripts/grid_run_exe.
py", line 10, in <module>
run_idx             : 7    run.main_grid_loop()
  File "C:\Users\mathee\CLionProjects\dphpc-project\python\libs\execution\GridRu
nHandler.py", line 141, in main_grid_loop
    sub_dir=sub_dir)
  File "C:\Users\mathee\CLionProjects\dphpc-project\python\libs\execution\GridRu
nHandler.py", line 86, in run_algorithm
    print '{:20}: {}'.format(key, value)
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

EDIT:
I re-installed python anacondy distribution, didn't help. I did run on a linux cluster -> works perfectly fine. I have run it in Windows shell -> works perfectly fine. It actually seems to be an issue with the CLion IDE. I re-installed Clion, updated the version, both did not solve the issue. I will post this on the JetBrains webpage and am forced to run from shell until then, which sucks because I cannot use the debugger.

Comment: you have a for loop outside, don't you?

Comment: The loop is over the function which defines the dictionary and does the print. The parameters are passed to the function. It also happens when I simply do print key, value without formatting btw. Originally using the parameters I do a subprocess call to some c++ code. Inside the c++ code I have print statements which sometimes were broken (simply not showing up or only partially). However I removed the the subprocess call and it turned out that there is an issue already only on the python side.

Comment: In which example it crashes? Which dict causes it to crash?

Comment: Sometimes it also crashes with the following statement:
print '\n', 30*'= '
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
Could it be an IDE specific thing? I have to test the code in the shell though, an error on this simple print statement seems amazingly odd to me.